# How do you use the Raster Calculator in ArcGIS to combine rasters using the Con statement

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator

So, I'm busy doing an assignment where we have to use a Weighted overlay to generate a raster of suitable places to plant crops. I've put all the factors in the weighted overlay and generated my output but now I need to consider the constraints. These are built up areas and conservation areas that need to be classified as 'not suitable'. The lecturer says that we need to use a CON statement in the raster calculator to get the '0' values from the constraint's raster put onto the weighted overlay raster.

But, I have no idea how to do that. All the resources I have found use the format CON (in raster = 0, x, y) but i don't know how to fill the Y value with an entire raster... if that makes sense?